# Kendo dragdrop not working?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

[image]

I am using Kendo dragdrop for my charts. Its woking fine for some of the charts where I use a different approach for showing the charts.

```
<div id="ExertiveHeartRate" class="chartContainer"></div>
<div id="BloodPressure" class="chartContainer"></div>



        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: createURL("AverageHeartRate", period1, period2, "<% = Session["id"] %>"),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
            async:"false",
            success: function (chartData) {


                $(container).kendoChart({

                    dataSource: {
                        data: chartData
                    },

                    seriesColors: ["orangered"],

                    chartArea: {
                        background: ""
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: title,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        visible: false
                    },

                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "column",
                        gap: .5,
                        overlay: {
                            gradient: "none"
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        field: "heartrate"                             
                    }],

                    categoryAxis: {
                        type: "date",
                        field: "createddate"                         
                    },
                    valueAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: "Exertive HeartRate",
                            font: "14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

If i create chart as above. drag-drop will not work. If I use the code as below, its working fine

```
var dSource = getJsonData("BloodPressure", period1, period2, "<% = Session["id"] %>");


        $(container).kendoChart({

            dataSource: dSource,

            seriesColors: ["#002EB8"],
            title: {
                text: title,
                font: "14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif bold",
                color: "#002EB8"
            },

            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },

            legend: {
                visible: false
            },

            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },

            seriesDefaults: {
                type:"column",
                gap: .5,
                overlay: {
                    gradient: "none"
                }
            },
            series: [
            {
                name: "diastolic",
                field: "diastolic",
                categoryField: "createddate",
                aggregate: "avg",
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true
            }],

            categoryAxis: {
                type: "date"
                },
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                majorTicks: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }
        });
```

The code for doing the dragdrop is below:

```
        $(".chartContainer").kendoDraggable({
            hint: function (e) {
                debugger;

                $("#" + e[0].id).addClass("dragStyle");
                return e.clone();
            },
            dragstart: function (e) {

                debugger;

                e.currentTarget.hide();
            },
            dragend: function (e) {
                if (!e.currentTarget.data("kendoDraggable").dropped) {
                    $("#" + e.currentTarget[0].id).addClass("dropStyle");
                }
                e.currentTarget.show();
            }
        });

        $(".chartContainer").kendoDropTarget({
            drop: function (e) {
                $("#" + e.draggable.element[0].id).addClass("dropStyle");
                $("#" + e.draggable.element[0].id).insertBefore("#" + e.dropTarget[0].id);
            }
        });
```

$.ajax() function has something which blocks the dragdrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$(container)` is a bad jquery selector. It should most likely be more like `$('#container')`.

Also you may want to wait to register the drag and drop functionality of kendo until after the chart has been made. So at the end of your success function in the ajax function.

---

You can also take another approach. You don't need your data to make the chart in the first place. Just declare your chart as normal. You can then pass in your data into the chart after it has loaded.

```
$.ajax({
  url:...,
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(d){
   $('#container').data('kendoChart').dataSource.data(d);
  }
});
```

You may want to display a loading image while you wait.